# Image's src attribute equals "[object Object]" when processed by Webpack

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin, webpack-html-loader

I'm using Webpack to process HTML and assets, here's the minimal `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const OUTPUT_DIR = __dirname + '/dist';

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + '/src',
  entry: './index.js',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'html-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.jpg$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin([
      OUTPUT_DIR
    ]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'index.html'
    })
  ],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: OUTPUT_DIR,
    publicPath: '/'
  }
};
```

My source `index.html`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Example Web Page</title>

</head>

<body>

  <img src="image.jpg">

</body>

</html>
```

The problem is that in the final HTML document the image tag looks like this: `<img src="[object Object]">`.

I'm using [`html-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) to generate the output HTML using my source HTML document as a template, which is loaded using [`html-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader).

The image is actually added to the output directory.

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "file-loader?name=images/[name].[ext]",
        options: {
          esModule: false
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: An answer without code has little value. Comments  bring your answers much more weight and much more value

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. After upgrading the dependencies (I'm using yarn for it: `yarn upgrade`) the problem gone away. This is a second bug in Webpack ecosystem during this weekend (crazy).